# Test Class Coverage improvement

Tags: apex, unit-test

Controller -

```
/** Controller to add Contacts to Portfolio Suspect  **/
/** vf page - MultiselectContactAC **/
/** GSI Project **/
/** Owner - Shikha Mishra **/

public with sharing class AddContacttoAttributedCampaign { 

    public AttributedCampaign__c attc;
    public ContactAttributedCampaign__c cac {get;set;} 
    public list<ContactAttributedCampaign__c> cacList{get;set;}
    public string attid; 
    public string accid; 
    @TestVisible public list<wrapContact> wrapContactList {get; set;} 
    public list<Contact> selectedContacts {get; set;}
    public integer totalRecs=0;
    public integer index =0;
    public integer blockSize = 100; 

    public AddContacttoAttributedCampaign(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.attc = (AttributedCampaign__c)stdController.getRecord();
        attid =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('attid'); 
        accid =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accid');
        cac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c();
        attc = new AttributedCampaign__c ();
        for(AggregateResult result :[SELECT COUNT(Id) intVal FROM Contact where AccountId=:accid]) {
            totalRecs+=(Integer)result.get('intVal');
        }

        cacList = [Select Name, Attributed_Campaign__c, Contact__c, Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c from ContactAttributedCampaign__c where Attributed_Campaign__c =: attid order by Name desc];
        wrapContactList = new list<wrapContact>();
        for (contact c : [Select Id, Name, title, Job_Role__c, Job_Function__c from Contact where AccountId =: accid and Contact_Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT : blockSize OFFSET:index]) {
            wrapContactList.add(new wrapContact(c));
        }        
    } 
    public void beginning() {   
        wrapContactList.clear();
        index = 0;
        for (contact c : [Select Id, Name, title, Job_Role__c, Job_Function__c from Contact where AccountId =: accid and Contact_Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT : blockSize OFFSET:index]) {
            wrapContactList.add(new wrapContact(c));
        }
    }

    public void previous() {
        wrapContactList.clear();   
        index = index - blockSize;
        if(index > 0) {
            for (contact c : [Select Id, Name, title, Job_Role__c, Job_Function__c from Contact where AccountId =: accid and Contact_Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT : blockSize OFFSET:index]) {
                wrapContactList.add(new wrapContact(c));
            }
        } else {
            beginning(); 
        }
    }

    public void next() {    
        wrapContactList.clear(); 
        index = index + blockSize;
        if(index < totalrecs ) {
            for (contact c : [Select Id, Name, title, Job_Role__c, Job_Function__c from Contact where AccountId =: accid and Contact_Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT : blockSize OFFSET:index]) {
                wrapContactList.add(new wrapContact(c));
            }
        } else {
            beginning();
        }        
    }

    public void end() {   
        wrapContactList.clear(); 
        index = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,blockSize);
        if(index > 0) {
            for (contact c : [Select Id, Name, title, Job_Role__c, Job_Function__c from Contact where AccountId =: accid and Contact_Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT : blockSize OFFSET:index]) {
                wrapContactList.add(new wrapContact(c));
            }
        } else {
            beginning();
        }
    }        

    Public PageReference SavePage() { 
        selectedContacts = new list<Contact>();
        Set<Id> cacID = new Set<Id>();
        for(ContactAttributedCampaign__c ca :cacList) {
            cacID.add(ca.Contact__c);
        }

        List<ContactAttributedCampaign__c> insertList = new List<ContactAttributedCampaign__c>();
        for(wrapContact wrapobj : wrapContactList) {
            if(wrapobj.isSelected == true) {
                if(!cacID.contains(wrapobj.conn.Id)) {
                    ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c() ;
                    conac.Attributed_Campaign__c = attid; 
                    conac.Contact__c = wrapobj.conn.id; 
                    conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c= wrapobj.mark;
                    insertList.add(conac);
                    wrapobj.isSelected =False;
                }
                for(ContactAttributedCampaign__c item : cacList) {
                    if(item.Contact__c == wrapobj.conn.id && item.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c != wrapobj.mark) {
                        ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = [select id,Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c from ContactAttributedCampaign__c where Attributed_Campaign__c = :attid and Contact__c = :wrapobj.conn.id];
                        conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c = wrapobj.mark;
                        insertList.add(conac);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        upsert insertList;

        cacList = [Select Name, Attributed_Campaign__c, Contact__c, Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c  from ContactAttributedCampaign__c where Attributed_Campaign__c =: attid order by Name desc];

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference redirectBack() {
        return new PageReference('/'+attid);
    }

    @TestVisible public class wrapContact {
        public Contact conn{get; set;}
        public ContactAttributedCampaign__c cac{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected {get; set;}
        public Boolean mark{get;set;}

        public wrapContact(Contact c) {
            this.conn = c;
            this.isSelected = false;                
        }
        public wrapContact(ContactAttributedCampaign__c d) {
            this.cac = d;
            this.isSelected = false;  
            this.mark  = d.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c;
        }
    }    
}
```

Test Class-

```
/** Test Class for Controller - AddContacttoAttributedCampaign **/
/** GSI Project **/
/** Owner - Shikha Mishra **/

@isTest
public with sharing class AddContacttoAttributedCampaign_Test {
    public static Account acc = new Account();
    public static Account acc1 = new Account();
    public static Campaign_Hierarchy__c ch = new Campaign_Hierarchy__c();
    public static AttributedCampaign__c ac = new AttributedCampaign__c();
    public static Contact cc = new Contact();
    public integer totalRecs=0;
    public integer index =0;
    public integer blockSize = 1;
    public static ContactAttributedCampaign__c cac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c();

    public static void setUpData() {
        acc.Name= 'TestAcc';
        acc.physical_street_1__c = 'Werner-von-Siemens-Str. 48-52';
        acc.physical_city__c = 'BAYERN';
        acc.UGS_Zone_Ownership__c = 'Germany';
        acc.type = 'Customer-Active';
        acc.Internal_Industry__c = 'Life Sciences';
        acc.currencyisocode = 'EUR';
        acc.physical_country__c = 'Germany';
        acc.Physical_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '92224';
        insert acc;

        cc.FirstName = 'Test';
        cc.LastName = 'Con';  
        cc.AccountId = acc.Id;
        cc.Job_Function__c = 'Automation';
        cc.Job_Role__c = 'Staff';
        cc.Contact_Status__c = 'Active';        
        insert cc;

        ch.Campaign_Master__c = 'E4E_Marine';
        ch.Global_Campaign__c = 'PDX_Syncrofit_Aerospace Innovation Kit for Airframe Design';
        insert ch;

        ac.Account__c = acc.id; 
        ac.Campaign_Hierarchy__c = ch.id;
        ac.Status__c ='Target';
        ac.Status_Change__c = system.today();    
        insert ac; 
    }

    public static testMethod void testAddContacttoAttributedCampaign() {       
        setUpData();

        test.startTest();

        cac.Attributed_Campaign__c = ac.id; 
        cac.Contact__c = cc.Id;
        cac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c = true;    
        insert cac;         

        test.stopTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(ac);
        AddContacttoAttributedCampaign controller = new AddContacttoAttributedCampaign(sc);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.MultiselectContactAC;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('attid',ac.Id);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('accid',acc.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        controller.beginning();
        controller.previous();
        controller.next();
        controller.Previous();
        controller.end();

        AddContacttoAttributedCampaign.wrapContact thisListItem = new AddContacttoAttributedCampaign.wrapContact(cc); 
        AddContacttoAttributedCampaign.wrapContact thisListItem2 = new AddContacttoAttributedCampaign.wrapContact(cac);

        controller.SavePage();
        controller.redirectBack();        
    }
}
```

I am able to get 67 covergae. Can someone help me to increase its coverage above 80. Thanks!

Comment: What are the not covered lines?

Comment: Lines after save method are not covering

Comment: if(wrapobj.isSelected == true){
                 if(!cacID.contains(wrapobj.conn.Id)){
                   ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c() ;
                   conac.Attributed_Campaign__c = attid; 
                   conac.Contact__c = wrapobj.conn.id; 
                   conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c= wrapobj.mark;
                   insertList.add(conac);
                   wrapobj.isSelected =False;
                   }

Comment: The if statement is telling you the answer. You need to mock items in your wrapper list as selected and then test the save method again in your test class.

Comment: I tried but it didnt worked. Is it possible for you to provide me code of line that can i add to it.  It will be very helpfull for me.

Comment: for(wrapContact wrapobj : wrapContactList){
            if(wrapobj.isSelected == true){
                 if(!cacID.contains(wrapobj.conn.Id)){
                   ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c() ;
                   conac.Attributed_Campaign__c = attid; 
                   conac.Contact__c = wrapobj.conn.id; 
                   conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c= wrapobj.mark;
                   insertList.add(conac);
                   wrapobj.isSelected =False;
                   }

Comment: Need to cover these lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no condition where isSelected is becoming to true..May be you are setting isSelected from front end..

In your controller code you can change a bit i.e.

```
for(wrapContact wrapobj : wrapContactList){
            if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
                wrapobj.isSelected = true;
            }
            if(wrapobj.isSelected == true){
                 if(!cacID.contains(wrapobj.conn.Id)){
                   ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = new ContactAttributedCampaign__c() ;
                   conac.Attributed_Campaign__c = attid; 
                   conac.Contact__c = wrapobj.conn.id; 
                   conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c= wrapobj.mark;
                   insertList.add(conac);
                   wrapobj.isSelected =False;
                   }
                       for(ContactAttributedCampaign__c item : cacList)
                       {
                       if(item.Contact__c == wrapobj.conn.id && item.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c != wrapobj.mark){
                               ContactAttributedCampaign__c conac = [select id,Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c from ContactAttributedCampaign__c where Attributed_Campaign__c = :attid and Contact__c = :wrapobj.conn.id];
                               conac.Include_in_Marketing_Activity__c = wrapobj.mark;
                               insertList.add(conac);
                               }
                           }
                 } 
            }
```

Hope so it will work..

Thanks,

Kirti Rathod

Salesforce Developer

http://www.zen4orce.com

Comment: Hi Kirti, Thanks but this didnot worked

Comment: You have to create different Contacts for cacList and wrapContactList because of this condition if(!cacID.contains(wrapobj.conn.Id)) ..